# How to remove layers data source M-awareness to publish editable featureServer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, feature-service, publishing

I would like to publish an editable feature layer (featureservice)  on my ArcGIS server. When I want to publish the data it warns however that the layer is m-aware. In the arcgis documentation I read that you can add or delete m-aware data but not edit the existing points. I do need this editability.

Is there a way to delete the m-awareness of a feature dataset?

The dataset is a layer of points, stored on a database (sqlexpress). I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to export your feature classes to feature classes.
Esri [HowTo: Remove Z- and/or M-values from a feature class](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35818)

```
1.Browse to ArcToolbox > Conversion Tools > To Geodatabase. 
2.Open the Feature Class to Geodatabase (multiple) tool. 
3.Add all the feature classes into the Input Feature Class parameter. 
4.Select an Output Geodatabase. 
5.Click the Environments button at the bottom of the tool dialog box. 
6.Expand the General Settings. 
7.For the parameter, Output has Z Values, change the value to Disabled. 
8.For the parameter, Output has M Values, change the value to Disabled. 
9.Click OK in the Environments dialog box. 
10.Click OK to execute the geoprocessing tool.
```

Comment: Indeed, I used the copy features tool to do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different process for ArcGIS 10.2: under Environment Settings, disable the M-values under M Values-->Output has M Values-->Disabled.Then run the Feature Class to Geodatabase or Copy Features tool. Same process for removing Z-aware, but Z-values-->Output has Z Values-->Disabled.